# Avoid duplicates using django ModelForm

Tags: django, model, modelform

I have the following Model, ModelForm and View:

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    clinicid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    label = models.SlugField(max_length=25)
    # logo =
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    alternate = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='', blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    pincode = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=80, default='', blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)

class ClinicMetaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Clinic
        fields = [
            'name',
            'label',
            'email',
            'mobile',
            'alternate',
            'about',
            'state',
            'city',
            'locality',
            'pincode',            
            'address',
            'website'
        ]
        unique_together = ["name", "mobile", "email"]

def newclinic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('New clinic setup')
        form = ClinicMetaForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        msg = "Successfully saved new clinic"
        print(msg)
    else:
        form = ClinicMetaForm()
        msg=''
    return render(request, 'clinic/newclinic.html', {'form': form, 'msg': msg})
```

The problem is that when the same data is submitted, I get duplicate entries being saved, even though I am using unique_together. Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

Comment: unique_together should be used in Model

Answer (score 0):

You should move [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to model.
And if you want to add some logic in your form just overwrite `validate_unique`

```
def validate_unique(self):
    #your logic here
    try:
        self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
    except ValidationError, e:
        self._update_errors(e.message_dict)
```